# REPL console in context of application in Go

Tags: go

Is there a way to access an interactive REPL console in the context of an application, in Go?

For reference, I'm thinking about the functionality of [Ruby's irb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interactive_Ruby_Shell) or [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) (and, by extension, the [Ruby On Rails console](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-console) that builds on them), the [Node.js REPL](https://nodejs.org/api/repl.html), the [Scala REPL](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/repl/overview.html) (and [Play console](https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.6.x/PlayConsole)) or [Elixir's IEx](https://hexdocs.pm/iex/IEx.html). All of these are development (or production!) tools to open a REPL in the context of an application. For example, they allow to access an application's classes, objects and constants, and by extension to interact with the application's resources (e.g. a database).

There are some Go REPLs out there, like [gore](https://github.com/motemen/gore), but it's not clear how to plug them into an application.

I suppose it would be possible to start a `gore` session and then import all packages, but what about the initializations that happen in the `main`?

My instinct tells me that there should be a way to provide an alternative "REPL-only" `main` to compile a different binary that starts the application as a REPL -- rather than, say, an HTTP server.

Is there any established way to do so? Or a reference implementation?

Answer (score 0):

You could try `go-pry`: https://github.com/d4l3k/go-pry

This works much close to the rails console. Just `import "github.com/d4l3k/go-pry/pry"` in your file and add `pry.Pry()` where you want to start your session. After that you just call `go-pry main.go` instead of `go main.go`.

But there is not a standard solution, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. `go-pry` is actually one of the packages I'm evaluating alongside `gore` but, funnily enough, it just panics and crashes on my system. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯